# Wpf Prism 6.2 Unity MVVM guidance needed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism-6

I used to work on WPF prism 4 with unity. And now coming back to the topic, a lot of things seem have changed.

I have already downloaded the sample project "ModularityWithUnity.Desktop" from https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

Which is a bit strange for me now, **there is no type registering anymore**. How the viewmodels, services are resolved at run time?

Comment: You can go through the [documentation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Documentation/WPF), but in short: UnityBootstrapper does most of the registering already. Resolving is standard IoC.

Comment: @Bart this is a reasonable question, there's no reason why a summary of what the doco says can't be excerpted here. Unfortunately "RTFM" isn't a valid reason to close a question.